# HTTP Security Header Not Detected - Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, http-headers

I ran a PCI scan over one app that I have and the report states a vulnerability - HTTP Security Header Not Detected. The report has a very straight forward explanation of what is causing and what the solution could be. Basically I need to set:
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains".

My app is a huge spring framework portal with 4 modules. After some research, I tried to adapt the Java Configuration that is described in docs.spring.io, using spring-security. It's looks like a simple change and that's why I'm wondering what might be wrong in my solution.

After adding the vulnerability fix I don't have any errors in the portal. The issue is that the PCI scan result was exactly the same, so my changes did nothing.

So, I added this java file on each module
..\src\main\java\src\is\compny\common\WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .headers()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);

    }
}
```

The `http.csrf().disable();` should fix the X-Content-Type-Options and the rest should fix the Strict-Transport-Security.

Am I missing something in this solution? Did I add the class on the wrong place? Do I have to call the configure method anywhere?

Thanks in advance!